# Vuepress - Netlify CMS - Error loading the CMS configuration

Tags: netlify-cms, vuepress

I'm make a Vuepress Blog and I would add to Netlify CMS in the backend.

The steps to implement Netlify CMS into Vuepress:

1. Create this path /blog/.vuepress/public/admin
2. Create a index.html into the path with this code:
3. In the same path create the config.yml:

   backend:
   name: github
   branch: master
   repo: githubusername/reponame
   publish_mode: editorial_workflow
   media_folder: ".vuepress/public/assets/img"
   public_folder: "img"
   collections:

   - name: "blog" # Used in routes, e.g., /admin/collections/blog
     label: "Blog" # Used in the UI
     folder: "blog/_posts"

[Here](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/add-to-your-site/#app-file-structure) official documentation.

Also the message is the same:

```
Error loading the CMS configuration<br>
Config Errors:<br>
config must have required property 'media_folder'<br>
config must have required property 'media_library'<br>
config must match a schema in anyOf<br>
config must have required property 'collections'<br>
Check your config.yml file.<br>
```

I'm not sure what is the problem because the file exist in /admin and the media_folder parameter is defined.

I'm read the Netlify CMS documentation and tutorials and I have linked the Github by Netlify connector.

Please Could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you indented the `config.yml` file properly? You could edit your question using a code block to we see clearly how your configuration is doing.
Note that `publish_mode`, `media_folder` and `public_folder` [should not be indented](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/add-to-your-site/#editorial-workflow).
Additionally, reading the [documentation](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/add-to-your-site/#editorial-workflow) I think `public_folder` must begin with a slash.